# Warning database has been locked for 0:00:10.000000. Make sure you always use the transaction object for database operations during a transaction

Tags: android, flutter

I am trying to get images from a remote server. I keep getting this error:

```
  Warning database has been locked for 0:00:10.000000. 
  Make sure you always use the transaction object for database operations during a transaction
```

And afterwards my application crash.

```
Widget carousel = new Container(
      height: 200,
      child: FutureBuilder<List<String>>(
          future: getPropImgs(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return new Carousel(
                
                boxFit: BoxFit.cover,
                images: snapshot.data.map((f) {
                  return new CachedNetworkImage(
                    imageUrl: f.toString(),
                    imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) => Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        image: DecorationImage(
                            image: imageProvider,
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            colorFilter:
                                ColorFilter.mode(Colors.blue, BlendMode.dstIn)),
                      ),
                    ),
                    placeholder: (context, url) => Center(
                        child: Container(
                            height: 30,
                            width: 30,
                            child: CircularProgressIndicator())),
                    errorWidget: (context, url, error) =>
                        Image.asset("assets/images/icon.png"),
                  );
                }).toList(),
                autoplay: true,
                animationCurve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
                animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
                indicatorBgPadding: 1.0,
                dotColor: Colors.black,
                
              );
```

Comment: Can you please share the relevant code with the database connection?

Comment: Please reply the answer if it is solved your problem.

Answer (score 19):

I guess you are trying to perform huge amount of SQL queries.
Once slow solution is to make sure you await every calls. In the second line here you are missing an await:

```
 await db.transaction((txn) async {
```

However here it still create one transaction per insert so that will be super slow. One solution is to use batches (https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/tree/master/sqflite#batch-support) and queue the insert statement (1000 by 1000 for example);

```
var batch = db.batch();
batch.rawInsert(statement1);
batch.rawInsert(statement2);
batch.rawInsert(statement3);
...
await db.commit(noResult: true);
```

Comment: First simple and useful answer I found about this issue; thanks, it helped a lot, @Ömer!

Answer (score -1):

DON'T CREATE A NEW DB VARIABLE INSIDE THE TRANSACTION...

**DON'T DO THIS**

```
 await db.transaction((txn) async {
  var batch = txn.database.batch();//Mistake. 
  batch.insert(/*..table...*/, /*..toJson()..*/);
   
});
```

**DO LIKE THIS**

```
await db.transaction((txn) async {

      txn.batch().insert(/*..table...*/, /*..toJson()..*/);
      txn.batch().insert(/*..table...*/, /*..toJson()..*/);
      txn.batch().insert(/*..table...*/, /*..toJson()..*/);
      txn.batch().insert(/*..table...*/, /*..toJson()..*/);
      try{
        await txn.batch().commit(continueOnError: true);
        print("SUCESS ID : COMMIT " );
      }catch(e){
        print("faied to save to commit BRECASE ==> ${e.toString()}");
      }
    });
```

Comment: It shows the SUCESS, but there is no data on the table

Comment: whatsapp me on +256783204665, i will be able to help you.

Comment: try to make continueOnError: false 
and see if you wll be able to see an error